# Community Promotion Ads 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites), and so with it, we now have finally reached the time to start Community Promotion Ads on your graduated site!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for understanding worlds
- blogs or articles of existing interesting worlds
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2902).

Comment: Traditionally, we would post a sample ad with the site's twitter, but unfortunately Worldbuilding does not have a twitter account yet. [Here's an example of one, though](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/704/community-promotion-ads-2016/705#705).

Comment: **Public Service Announcement:** Can we please use protocol-relative or HTTPS image URLs whenever possible? A protocol-relative URL omits the `http:` or `https:` at the beginning, starting with `//` (for example, `//www.example.com/image.png` which becomes a HTTP URL if you are browsing over HTTP, but a HTTPS URL if you are browsing over HTTPS). That way, when the community ad shows up on the front page, people who browse the site over HTTPS (such as those who run EFF's *HTTPS Everywhere*) don't get hit with mixed content warnings. Make sure to test that both variants work. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/community-promotion-ads-2017)

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's an annual event, so of course there will be multiple questions about this. However, they have different answers, as every year has a different climate, so they are not duplicates of each other.

Comment: @Zxyrra Normally we mark them as duplicates of each other, so that all posts go towards the current cycle. I'm pretty sure it's shuts off earlier ads from running as well, essentially resetting the ads and making sure only the new ads in the 2017 posts are shown.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Visit Writers Stack Exchange]

Comment: The delegation from Writers.SE humbly requests ad space on Worldbuilding.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  Writers' not  Writers in the tagline?

Comment: @TimB the official SE name doesn't have an apostrophe (same as Programmers and probably some others).

Comment: I get a file size of 81.4KB. Someone else want to check?

Comment: @nitsua60 oh, I guess they haven't updated these posts yet -- we've been told that it's now ok to go up to 150k like last year.  Too many sites were having too many problems fitting in 40k.

Comment: @Michael Hate to break it, but the ads, even if served over https, redirect to an http meta world building link, so it won't really work :/

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm not sure what you are implying? The point is to grab the ad images themselves over HTTPS, because (as I mentioned in chat asking for feedback before making these changes) the only non-HTTPS content (when loading over HTTPS) on the front page was the ad image itself. Loading the ad image over HTTPS got rid of the mixed content warning. Where it links to is immaterial.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Share your work on the blog -- we'll help!]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Visit Universe Factory]

Comment: I get 158 KB =(

Comment: File-size limit is now 150 KB (not the original 40), so we're close here.

Comment: Filesize is too high, must be reduced to below 150 KB

Comment: Wow, that’s ugly!

Answer (score 11):

[image: RPG.SE]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Support the Literature proposal!]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Discuss the real world. Start Urban Planning SE!]

Comment: Start a place to discuss the real world! Generally, I try to custom draw these ads, mostly because I think the A51 ads are rather ugly, but I'm just trying to get these out, and hopefully I'll get a real ad up when I'm finished with my exams :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Help support the Cartography SE in Area 51]

Comment: Proposed Q&A site for those interested in maps and map-making, historical or contemporary, real or fictional. I believe this would be a good fit for the Worldbuilding community for resources on maps and map-making ideas and methods for games, novels, and well...  anything, really.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Proposed Q&A site for enthusiasts, developers, students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone else wanting to discuss constructed languages (Esperanto, Volapük, Dovahzul, Vulcan, etc.)]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Paranormal]