# Blog on mobile devices

Tags: support, blog

I am interested about the Worldbuilding blog and would like to read some of the stuff in it but I cannot find it. The blog link at the bottom of the page takes me to stack overflow blog not Universe Factory. I am using a mobile device if that makes a difference. I seem to remember finding the blog on a desktop computer once but would like to find it on mobile.

Comment: HDEs answer covers it, but I would also mention that Medium has an app for android/iOS and you can favorite the blog so its easy to find from your mobile device.

Answer (score 3):

As Monica brought up in [Can we have an SE blog for this site?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2504/627), Stack Exchange is no longer doing many official per-site blogs, for various reasons. Therefore, [our blog, Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory) is officially un-official and technically unaffiliated with Stack Exchange in any way, shape, or form, except for the fact that everyone who writes for it is a member of the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange community.

This means that there isn't a link to it on the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, as there is for the official blog(s). Therefore, you can either bookmark the link on your computer, or find it somewhere on the site, such as in this answer. A better bet is [in the blog tag wiki excerpt](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/blog/info). Also, there's a link to it on [one community promotion ad](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2922/627) that sometimes shows up on the sidebar; that might have been what you originally clicked on.

<sup>Fun fact: We previously had a Wordpress Blog, [Magrathean Forges](http://magratheanforges.wordpress.com/), but that folded after one or two entries because of lack of interest; the content was transferred to the Medium blog. Before today, the link in the tag excerpt led to *that* blog, rather than Universe Factory. I edited the link to correct this.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for updating the tag wiki, which I'm embarrassed to say I had not noticed existed.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I didn't notice it either until I searched through the [tag:blog] questions, trying to find something to cite.