# Community Ad for Cartography in Area 51

Tags: discussion

I've proposed a new site, "[Cartography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101932/cartography?referrer=eB8KJkkaBh0tAmQDgW1TOg2)" in Area 51: Proposed Q&A site for those interested in maps and map-making, historical or contemporary, real or fictional.  I believe that others in the Worldbuilding community might be interested in such a site for their work and to see other ideas, both fictional and real, with regards to creating maps for games and novels - or really for anything.

I know advertising this in the non-meta is disallowed on SE sites, but I'm not sure how community ads work, or if it's something that enough people would think was a good thing to point the Worldbuilder community toward.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can propose an ad on [Community Promotion Ads 2016](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/community-promotion-ads-2016) (and the corresponding page for next year, come January).  If it gets voted up it will become part of the rotation.  There's a standard template for Area 51 ads (you can see several examples on that page).  If you prefer to make your own graphic, that's fine too.  Note that the Area 51 ads have live stats (current number of committers, etc), so that's useful.