# Bug in the pinned Blog links on the sidebar

Tags: bug, blog, hyperlinks

This morning I saw the link on the sidebar to the pinned blog post, "Calculating Political Power", which I thought was interesting, so I clicked on it. However, it took me to the [Stop Saying Rivers Only Converge](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/new-blog-post-stop-saying-rivers-only-converge), instead. Even when I try to type in the URL or copy the location for the political power post, it redirects me automatically to the "Stop Saying Rivers Only Converge" Meta post, instead.

Now both of those links are showing on the side bar and they both go directly (or redirect to) the Rivers post. I believe it is because they both link to question number 4037, which is the important part of the URL for telling which question to link to.

How can I find the Political Power post, and can that sidebar behavior be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post links are made directly to the "New blog post" question, which has a running list of all of the prior blog posts in the answers below. The question itself gives a short description of the current blog post. At the moment, we have two blog posts listed as "events", because they went up on the blog within a short time of each other, and it seemed best to promote both, rather than let the first one only get a little bit of the spotlight. Therefore, both are listed in the question, and so both events go to the same place.

Now we *could* fix the whole mess once and for all by simply linking each event to its corresponding blog post. However, Shog9 raised some points against doing so (starting in the transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32996589#32996589)):

- There's no easy way to audit an event, in the same way you can audit [Community Promotion Ads](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2902/627). Having off-site links can make folks uncomfortable - perhaps rightfully so.
- Having a single meta post reduces clutter over individual meta posts and makes it easy to track past "events".

Comment: Shouldn't the old blog post go to 4038, then? (That's the answer link, rather than 4037, the question link)

Comment: @TylerH Both are being kept in the question for the sake of promotion. The first will be added to the answer after its allotted period runs out - in a day or so.

Comment: It's just a little confusing the way it works now, though the first is already included in the answer as of this comment.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, right. I missed that. I think we'll leave it in until the event ends. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, I should have reflected both posts in the title to give a stronger clue, and have now done so.  As HDE 226868 said in another answer, we didn't want to cut off the earlier post's time in the spotlight just yet, but there's just the one meta post to link to.

Community events can only link to pages on SE somewhere, not posts on off-site blogs.  I discussed the reasons and proposed some mitigation in my answer to a [related question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288958/162102).  That analysis was a direct result of Shog's objections to event links.