# Is it okay to post here to promote a different Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support

Since this site has so many questions about military topics, I would like to post an invitation here asking people to join a proposed Stack Exchange for military technology and military culture.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria

Is it okay to post an invitation here even if it is not a question?

Answer (score 7):

Sure! We have a specific place for doing it, though: **Community Promotion Ads.**

Post an image advertising the proposal as an answer to [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4377/627). If it gets six upvotes or more, your ad will then be shown periodically on the right sidebar, where people can click through to get to the proposal. This system lets the community vet what they do and don't want to promote, while still giving the ad plenty of promotion.

There are a couple of requirements your answer needs to follow, but they're detailed in the linked question. Be especially careful about size and formatting. There are some examples of promoting Area 51 proposals in the linked thread, as well as from [2016](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2902/627).

Finally, do try to make sure that the proposal is in some way relevant to the site. I'm not sure how much attention Militaria will garner on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. It's worth a shot though; please do try it.

Comment: The size requirements should be the same this year as last.  It was from 2015 to 2016 that they changed.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm misremembering then, thanks. Some differences in size among the images posted threw me off.

Comment: Note that just trying to post an A51 ad as a CPA won't work. You have to post an ad that's uploaded to imgur and is  the right size,, and then you can edit it to be the A51 ad. Annoying, but it's the only way to do it.